# Sencha xtype methods

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have a question about xtypes. When I do this:

```
// map

var map = new Ext.map({
    fullscreen: true,
    getLocation: true,
    mapOptions: {
        zoom: 12
    }
});

map.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(record.attributes.record.data.latitude, record.attributes.record.data.longitude));
```

Everything is fine, the map is showing up.

Now, when I work with xtypes, the 'map'-variable won't recognize the 'setCenter'-property.
Code:
    var map =
    {
        fullscreen: true,
        xtype: 'map',
        title: 'Map',
        getLocation: true,
        useCurrentLocation: true,
        mapOptions:
        {
            zoom: 12
        }
    };

```
map.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(record.attributes.record.data.latitude, record.attributes.record.data.longitude));
```

With this code, I get this in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method
>   'setCenter' of undefined

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are calling `map.map.setCenter()`, your map object has already been instantiated. By defining your map with xtype, lazy instantiation is used.

You could try somethign along the lines of:

```
{
    xtype: 'map',
    fullscreen: true,
    getLocation: true,
    mapOptions: {
        zoom: 12
    },
    listeners: {
        maprender: function(component, map) {
            map.setCenter( ... )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm playing around with the xtypes, now I have the same with a Panel.

// description
var description =
{
 xtype: 'panel',
 tpl: '{title}'
};       description.update(record.attributes.record.data);

This gives me an error that the method 'update' is not known... Do I have to solve this the same way?

Comment: Yeah, I believe so. In the documentation, you can have a look at the different events you can plugin into in a Panel (e.g. maprender is an event for Map).